# INSERT varchar from a UTF-8 text file into MSSQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am inserting a text file into the database with my following query:

DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @json = BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\mydata.db', SINGLE_CLOB) AS [Insert]

```
INSERT INTO [neDB].[dbo].[tbl_api] (
    number
    ,DESC
    ,inf
    )
SELECT number
    ,DESC
    ,inf
FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT (
            '['
            ,REPLACE(@json, CONCAT (
                    '}'
                    ,CHAR(10)
                    ,'{'
                    ), '},{')
            ,']'
            )) WITH (
        number VARCHAR(200) '$.number'
        ,DESC VARCHAR(50) '$.desc'
        ,inf VARCHAR(150) '$.inf'
        )
```

The file "mydata.db" is UTF-8 which contains ü,ä,ö, etc. which will be stored as "Ã¼", "Ã¶" ... in the table.
If I convert the file to ANSI, all looks fine, but I don't want to convert the file all the time. Is there a way to design the query to insert UTF-8 directly?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2019? If not then it's time to upgrade, as prior versions don't support UTF-8, or change the code page of the file.

Comment: If you *are* using SQL Server 2019, what is the collation of the database/column?

Comment: Its a 2017 which I can't update, because it's a cutomer server. Thanks for the information, I will try to make a script to convert it before inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the parameter

```
CODEPAGE = '65001'
```

to the `OPENROWSET` call, which is the codepage for UTF-8 ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql)).

Comment: According to the [grammar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax), providing a CODEPAGE is only possible when using a format file, and the `SINGLE_BLOB | SINGLE_CLOB | SINGLE_NCLOB` options are mutually exclusive with that. `SINGLE_CLOB` is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#single_clob) as always using the collation of the current database, which indeed is the case.